# Explanation to executing a REST request

Tags: .net, rest, console

I'm having some trouble grasping exactly what this snippet of code I've run across does in a console application. I'm new to both console applications and REST and am having trouble finding answers online. Could someone explain to me what this code does, perhaps per line?

```
 public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()  
 {  
    var client = new RestClient();  
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

    if(response.ErrorException != null)  
    {      
        const string message = "Error occurred.";
        var pardotException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw pardotException;
     }
     return response.Data;
 }
```

From my basic knowledge, it looks like this is a method definition for a REST request in a console app. I see basic error handling and the definition for where to send the request, but I'm missing the overall purpose of this code segment.

EDIT: Is there any obvious way to optimize this code further? I now understand the method's purpose but could it be done better?

Answer (score 0):

This is a code using [`RestSharp`](http://restsharp.org/) library:

```
// Method that takes RestRequest and returns an object of generic type T
// (taken from response, we can assume here)
public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()  
{
    // Create client that will be able to call REST service
    var client = new RestClient();  
    // Provide the address of REST service
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    // Call service, specifing that its response will be deserialized to T
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

    if(response.ErrorException != null)  
    {      
        const string message = "Error occurred.";
        var pardotException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw pardotException;
     }
     // get the deserialized response object
     return response.Data;
 }
```